# Ruby script throwing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, watir

I want to write a Ruby script to check if the layer found in DOM in Firebug for a page(For example: `www.google.com`) is matching with the hash values declared in my script. Below is the Ruby script I have written:

```
require 'watir'

browser = Watir::Browser.new(:chrome)

browser.goto('www.google.co.in')

#Function
def page_data_layer(browser)
    page_layer  = {
        'host'     => 'www.google.co.in',
        'hostname' => 'www.google.co.in',
        'pathname' => '/',
        'protocol' => 'https:'
    }

    if page_layer.each do |data|
        data.has_key?('host')
            message.push("#{data['host']} matches")
        end
    end

    return message.join("\n")
end

#Main script
layer = page_data_layer(browser)

layer = Hash.new{|key,value| key[value] =
                  Hash.new(&key.default_proc)}

layer = browser.execute_script("return _gjwl")

log < layer
```

Following is the error I got when I ran the srcipt in Netbeans.

```
C:/Users/ruby_script.rb:17:in `block in page_data_layer': undefined method `has_key?' for ["host", "www.google.co.in"]:Array (NoMethodError)
        from C:/Users/ruby_script.rb:16:in `each'
        from C:/Users/ruby_script.rb:16:in `page_data_layer'
        from C:/Users/ruby_script.rb:26:in `<main>'
```

What I want to achieve is - `layer = browser.execute_script("return _gjwl")` will return whatever is available in the google site content for `_gjwl`. Hash is to match whether the key values are the same whatever is there in the google site content. So compare both and see if it matches, return pass or fail through message

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It might help if you can clarify what exactly you are trying to achieve. The code seems fragmented, which makes it hard to align it with the description. For example, why are you checking for a key in a hash you created? Why do you keep re-assigning values to the layer variable?

Comment: @Justin Ko what I want to achieve is - layer = browser.execute_script("return _gjwl") will return whatever is available in the google site content for _gjwl. Hash is to match whether the key values are the same whatever is there in the google site content. So compare both and see if it matches, return pass or fail

Comment: Anyone can help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 problems:

1. You are trying to compare the layers in the method, but only have access to the expected layer (not that returned by the browser).
2. You are iterating through the expected layer values, but only check itself for keys.

Here is what you need. You can re-factor it into methods as needed.

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
at_exit { browser.close }
browser.goto('www.google.co.in')

page_layer  = {
   'host'     => 'www.google.co.in',
   'hostname' => 'www.google.co.in',
   'pathname' => '/',
   'protocol' => 'https:'
}

layer = browser.execute_script("return _gjwl")
# => {"ancestorOrigins"=>[], "assign"=>{}, "hash"=>"", "host"=>"www.google.co.in", "hostname"=>"www.google.co.in", "href"=>"https://www.google.co.in/?gws_rd=ssl", "origin"=>"https://www.google.co.in", "pathname"=>"/", "port"=>"", "protocol"=>"https:", "reload"=>{}, "replace"=>{}, "search"=>"?gws_rd=ssl"}

page_layer.each do |key, value|
    # Output key being checked
    p key

    # Check if the value returned from the browser matches the expected value
    p value == layer[key]
end
```

Which gives a result of:

```
"host"
true
"hostname"
true
"pathname"
true
"protocol"
true
```

In terms of testing the results, you should probably look into some of the test frameworks. They give powerful comparison tools and reporting for a lot less work. For example, if using RSpec, comparing the values would be as simple as:

```
expect(layer).to include(page_layer)
```

If you want it a method that returns a combined results message:

```
def page_data_layer(layer)
  page_layer  = {
    'host'     => 'www.google.co.in',
    'hostname' => 'www.google.co.in',
    'pathname' => '/',
    'protocol' => 'https:'
  }

  page_layer.map do |key, value|
    result = value == layer[key] ? 'matches' : 'does not match'
    "#{key} #{result}"
  end.join("\n")
end

layer = browser.execute_script("return _gjwl")
puts page_data_layer(layer)
#=> "host matches"
#=> "hostname matches"
#=> "pathname matches"
#=> "protocol matches"
```

Comment: Justin Ko, thank you so very much....but, I want to write this in the form of function and then call it in the main script

Comment: Let me see if i can try

Comment: Can you clarify which part you want in the function vs main script? Given the original example, you have this whole part in the function (with the addition of building a message as opposed to direct output).

Comment: I want the hash page_layer with 'code' page_layer.each do |key, value|;
p key;p value == layer[key];end'code' in the function and only the matching of 'code' layer = browser.execute_script("return _gjwl")'code' should be in main script. Is that possible? My intention is that most part of possible code should be covered in function so that it can be used for more main scripts

Comment: Thanks a lot sir...you made my day

Answer (score 0):

`page_layer` is a `Hash` instance. Iterating hash passes `key, value` pair to the block. You are trying to call `has_key?` on it:

```
if page_layer.each do |data|
    data.has_key?('host')
        message.push("#{data['host']} matches")
    end
end
```

One might do:

```
message.push("#{data['host']} matches") if page_layer.has_key?('host')
```

or:

```
page_layer.each do |key, value|
  message.push("#{value} matches") if key == 'host'
end
```

Comment: Hi @mudasobwa. What should I do in the main script to check if it matches?

Comment: waiting for your answer

Comment: “waiting for your answer”—Cool to know.

Comment: I have deleted. 'Waiting for your answer ' - I meant regarding the main script to ask where am I going wrong. Really apologize if I have hurted you by my comment

Comment: Anyone can help me out?